# Is HTML and <canvas> suitable for an online Gameboy-style game?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, canvas, online-game

I'm planning on creating an online Gameboy-style game (I'm planning on trying to recreate the game as true-to-life as possible without directly emulating it), but I'm not certain what technology I might use.

For reference, I'm intending to try to recreate the [Gameboy Color's Pokémon Trading Card Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Trading_Card_Game_%28video_game%29). ([video example here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1igDbNxRfUw))
The game does not use a lot of constant background-redrawing, and mostly involves what I would guess would be sprite animation and keyframed animations.

Is the HTML `<canvas>` element with Javascript well-suited to handle simple 2D frame-by-frame updated animations, or would another technology be better-suited to handle it? Would there be an HTML solution for reliable audio as well?

Comment: the game you want to recreate contains also Copyrights....

Comment: If I were to publish it online and claim it as my own, that would be an issue, yes.

Comment: copyright infringement = a violation of the rights secured by a copyright. you cant use it, even for your personal use. nothing more to say.

Comment: Wonderful. That's also not the topic of what I'm asking.

Comment: Was there a portion of your question I was unable to answer?

Comment: @rrowland: The above comments weren't directed at you - I'm just waiting to give myself a little more time to review your answer. At a glance, it looks fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! If you're willing to learn it, HTML5 (Including the Canvas element) is capable of creating full-scale games within a browser window.
Check out mozilla's experimental game: http://browserquest.mozilla.org

If you're interested in learning more about HTML5, its features and good coding practices you should check out: http://www.html5rocks.com